# highcharts from event LegendItemClick to event textItemClick and iconItemClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

how to can change the code to add the event alert just by clicking the icon or symbol and remains the default event (visible and invisible chart ) just on the text of legend

```
plotOptions: {
        line: {

           events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                   alert('I am an alert');
                   //return false; 
                   // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                    }
                }
            ,
            showInLegend: true
        }
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LDMAQ/)

Comment: want to separate the two events , when a click on text , another when in click on icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare `target`'s:

```
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        var target = event.browserEvent.target;

                        if (target.tagName === "text") {
                            console.log("Text");   
                        } else {
                            console.log("Marker");
                        }
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LDMAQ/412/

Comment: thank you Pawel , well done that's exactly what I want.
 
it's missing something , in the click on the text , I want to ignore the show / hide of Selected chart,  what I 'll add to (target.tagName ==="text" ) {